# How to solve weird corners of rounded borders in CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, user-interface, border

Consider the following output:

[image: Username and Password Inputs]

In the output, you can notice weird corners in the username input (extra white-colored edges.) But they do not appear in the password input.

What might be causing this? Is there any way in CSS to fix this weird behavior?

(Note: I use Chrome as my browser.)

I looked for solutions on Google, but did not find any. I would like the weird corners of the rounded border to not appear.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#input-box{
outline: none !important;
width: 60%;
height: 38px;
padding: 8px 10px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
color: #555555;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #c1bdb8;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
-webkit-transition: all border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s ease-out;
-o-transition: all border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s ease-out;
transition: all border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s ease-out;
border-radius: 0 !important;
-webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Enter Something">
```